# Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field (of characteristic $\neq 2$). Question about linear maps $X,Y$ such that $X^2 = Y^2 = I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ (with $\text{char}(\mathbb{F}) \neq 2$). Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are linear maps such that $X^2 = Y^2 = I$ where $I: V \to V$ is the identity map. Show that if $YX = \lambda XY$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ then $\lambda \in \{ \pm 1\}$.

I have already showed that $X$ and $Y$ are diagonalizable with eigenvalues in $\{\pm 1\}$.

I tried to play around with the equation $YX - \lambda XY = 0$ to get it into a form that would indicate that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue but I ended up going in circles. I think there's probably a quick and easy way to do this, but my brain is stuck.

Comment: **Hint.** Suppose there is an eigenvector $v$ of $Y$ wrt the eigenvalue $1$. Then $v X = v Y X = \lambda (v X) Y$, so that $v X$ is an eigenvector of $Y$ wrt the eigenvalue...

Comment: If $YX=\lambda XY$ then $(YX)^2$ is a homothecy because
$$YX(YX)=\lambda XY(YX)=\lambda$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an eigenvector $v$ of $Y.$ As you have noted, the associated eigenvalue is $\pm 1.$ Apply the left hand side to $v.$ You get $\pm \lambda X v.$ Apply the right hand side to $v$. You get $Y X v.$ So, $X v$ is an eigenvector of $Y$ with eigenvalue $\pm \lambda.$ You can finish now.

Comment: Thanks. After what you've written, is it enough to just say "so $\lambda = \pm 1$, as these are the only eigenvalues of $Y$"? Or is there anything else I need to show?

Comment: @MathFrak96 Sounds good to me.